# Access 2010 - Last Sunday in March & October

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I have a series of dates, which are recorded in both BST and GMT (depending upon the time of year).  I want them to all be in GMT but I can't work out how to get Access to return the last Sunday in March (when we switch from GMT to BST) and the last Sunday in October (when we switch back).

All help appreciated!

I'm working in Access 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this generic function:

```
' Calculates the date of the occurrence of Weekday in the month of DateInMonth.
'
' If Occurrence is 0 or negative, the first occurrence of Weekday in the month is assumed.
' If Occurrence is 5 or larger, the last occurrence of Weekday in the month is assumed.
'
' If Weekday is invalid or not specified, the weekday of DateInMonth is used.
'
' 2016-06-09. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function DateWeekdayInMonth( _
    ByVal DateInMonth As Date, _
    Optional ByVal Occurrence As Integer, _
    Optional ByVal Weekday As VbDayOfWeek = -1) _
    As Date

    Const DaysInWeek    As Integer = 7

    Dim Offset          As Integer
    Dim Month           As Integer
    Dim Year            As Integer
    Dim ResultDate      As Date

    ' Validate Weekday.
    Select Case Weekday
        Case _
            vbMonday, _
            vbTuesday, _
            vbWednesday, _
            vbThursday, _
            vbFriday, _
            vbSaturday, _
            vbSunday
        Case Else
            ' Zero, none or invalid value for VbDayOfWeek.
            Weekday = VBA.Weekday(DateInMonth)
    End Select

    ' Validate Occurence.
    If Occurrence <= 0 Then
        Occurrence = 1
    ElseIf Occurrence > 5 Then
        Occurrence = 5
    End If

    ' Start date.
    Month = VBA.Month(DateInMonth)
    Year = VBA.Year(DateInMonth)
    ResultDate = DateSerial(Year, Month, 1)

    ' Find offset of Weekday from first day of month.
    Offset = DaysInWeek * (Occurrence - 1) + (Weekday - VBA.Weekday(ResultDate) + DaysInWeek) Mod DaysInWeek
    ' Calculate result date.
    ResultDate = DateAdd("d", Offset, ResultDate)

    If Occurrence = 5 Then
        ' The latest occurrency of Weekday is requested.
        ' Check if there really is a fifth occurrence of Weekday in this month.
        If VBA.Month(ResultDate) <> Month Then
            ' There are only four occurrencies of Weekday in this month.
            ' Return the fourth as the latest.
            ResultDate = DateAdd("d", -DaysInWeek, ResultDate)
        End If
    End If

    DateWeekdayInMonth = ResultDate

End Function
```

Then:

```
LastSundayMarch = DateWeekdayInMonth(DateSerial(Year(SomeDateOfYear), 3, 1), 5, vbSunday)

LastSundayOctober = DateWeekdayInMonth(DateSerial(Year(SomeDateOfYear), 10, 1), 5, vbSunday)
```

or as functions:

```
Public Function DateLastSundayMarch(ByVal DateOfYear As Date) As Date

    DateLastSundayMarch = DateWeekdayInMonth(DateSerial(Year(DateOfYear), 3, 1), 5, vbSunday)

End Function

Public Function DateLastSundayOctober(ByVal DateOfYear As Date) As Date

    DateLastSundayOctober = DateWeekdayInMonth(DateSerial(Year(DateOfYear), 10, 1), 5, vbSunday)

End Function
```

Now you can have expressions like:

```
=DateLastSundayOctober([SomeDateField])
```

to be used as ControlSource for a control or in the GUI query designer.

Comment: I'm not too experienced with VBA.  I've created a new module in my database (automatically has the line "Option Compare Database").  Do you mean that I copy and paste the generic function into the module underneath that  line and then put the LastSundayMarch etc in the same module or does it go somewhere else?

Thanks

Comment: The function is a copy-paste, but the two expressions are for use elsewhere. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
Option Explicit

Function getLastSundayOfMarchOfThisYear() As Date
    getLastSundayOfMarchOfThisYear = getLastSundayOfMonthOfThisYear(3)
End Function

Function getLastSundayOfOctoberOfThisYear() As Date
    getLastSundayOfOctoberOfThisYear = getLastSundayOfMonthOfThisYear(10)
End Function

Private Function getLastSundayOfMonthOfThisYear(month As Long) As Date
    Debug.Assert month >= 1 And month <= 12
    Dim i           As Long, _
        tmpDate     As Date, _
        daysInMonth As Long

    daysInMonth = Day(DateSerial(year(Date), month + 1, 1) - 1)
    For i = daysInMonth To 1 Step -1
        tmpDate = CDate(year(Date) & "-" & month & "-" & i)
        If Weekday(tmpDate) = vbSunday Then
            getLastSundayOfMonthOfThisYear = tmpDate
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```